# Block XMLHTTP request vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a scenario, where i need to cancel third party library request based on some condition and then unblock if condition evaluates to false. Let us assume that third party URL is being loaded with following URL:

```
https://cdn-thirdparty.com/...
```

Now, once it is loaded, it captures user clicks on the application and sends data as another URL:

```
https://cdn-info-thirdpart.com/...
```

Now, say i want to block all the requests to URL which contains `thirdparty` in it.. How do i achieve this in Vanilla Javascript...
P.S: I do not have access to remove the library from code, instead i have to do some engineering that requests are getting blocked based on some conditions(we can assume any) and then getting unblocked on falsy condition.

The code i tried to intercept all XMLHttpRequest is as below and i do get URL, method of call but i need to block it now and then unblock.

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
 window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
   // do something with the method, url and etc.
   this.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // do something with the response text
  console.log('load: ' + url, method);
});

 return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Source of above code: https://medium.com/@gilfink/quick-tip-creating-an-xmlhttprequest-interceptor-1da23cf90b76

Comment: couldn't you just... *not* apply the oldXHROpen method in that case?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.. can u go for any demo.. let us you try to block google map API request from your application

Comment: What i meant was, in your code, you have `return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);`. If you don't want the ajax request to be called, don't do that. Note however that if the 3rd party library is instead using fetch, fetch will still function... so you'll have to monkeypatch that one too.

Comment: yeah.. i agree but those third party library call are not getting intercepted.. for an instance of google analytics or google maps API call